# Kendo chart- Change categoryAxis Labels position as per the data value

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-chart

I am displaying Kendo column chart. I have a requirement to change categoryAxis labels positions as per the negative and positive value so that they don't overlap with the bars. Like the one in below image. I tried the label rotation property, but it gets applied to all the bars irrespective of it's value. Is there any workaround to achieve this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebXG0.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use the axis crossing value property
[here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/xaxis.axiscrossingvalue) is the documentation

They can be set for both axis and it will make the labels apear at the right place.

Here is a sample

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
  
  var myMinValue = -8;
  
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    series: [{
      data: [-4,-7,10]
    }],
    categoryAxes: [{
      categories: ["A", "B", "C"]
    }],
    valueAxis:  {
      axisCrossingValues: myMinValue
    }
});
</script>
```

Let's say you pass the value of your lowest number to a variable **myMinValue**

Comment: Being new to Kendo charts, I don't understand how this property can fulfill my requirement. I can't find suitable example as well.

Comment: please post some code so I can change my answer with a code sample

Comment: Thanks for quick help. I have created this sample code. You can see the labels overlapping on the bars. Please guide me on how to get rid of the overlapping issue. https://dojo.telerik.com/OkuQasuD

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to adjusting your chart's axis crossing value(s), you can also override the `visual` handler in the `labels` object which is good for getting customized looks down to the pixel. You can find the documentation on the function [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/series.labels.visual).

Here is some example code on one way to do this:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
  $("#chart").kendoChart({
    seriesDefaults: {
      type: "column",
      color: "#FFFF00",
      labels: {
        visible: true,
        visual: adjustLabels,
        template: "#: series.name  #"
      },
    },
    series: [
      { name : "abc", data: [ 5 ] },
      { name : "pqr", data: [ 3 ] },
      { name : "xsd", data: [ 6 ] },
      { name : "lkm", data: [ -3 ] },
      { name : "hyu", data: [ -6 ] },
      { name : "jui", data: [ 4 ] },
      { name : "qas", data: [ 5 ] },
      { name : "ghy", data: [ -8 ] },
    ]
  });

  function adjustLabels(e) {    
    var layout = new kendo.drawing.Layout(e.rect);
    
    if (e.stackValue < 0) {
     // put the label above the x-axis 
        var label = new kendo.drawing.Text(
        e.text, 
        [e.rect.origin.x, 163]
      );  
    } else {
      // put the label below the x-axis
      var label = new kendo.drawing.Text(
        e.text, 
        [e.rect.origin.x, 185]
      ); 
    }
    
    layout.append(label);
    //layout.reflow(); //uncomment this line to make the labels appear at the end of the bars
    return layout;
  }
</script>
```

You can also check out [this](https://dojo.telerik.com/uFuHIkUk) dojo example I made to see it running.

Comment: Looks all good from the example! Will surely try this out and post my response. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I tried the code you shared. I am using the categoryAxis field for displaying labels. I have created the below dojo example. It works fine for short labels. But the long labels are overlapping each other. I tried the rotation: auto property. But it's not working. Can you suggest something to avoid overlapping? https://dojo.telerik.com/EMIGaNiw

Comment: I'm not aware of anything simple to solve that, you'd be better off asking that in a different question.

Comment: No issues. Thank you for your help though. I solved the issue with some help from Telerik guys. Here is the [link](https://dojo.telerik.com/@Silvia/ITOziNaZ) of working example in case anyone comes across such problem